# Unable to start minikube with Hyper-V on windows 10

Tags: windows, kubernetes, hyper-v, minikube, hypervisor

When I run this command:

> minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv

minikube cannot start and displays the following error:

> minikube v1.7.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
>
> Using the hyperv driver based on user configuration
>
> ! 'hyperv' driver reported an issue: C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online failed:
>
> Suggestion: Start PowerShell as Administrator, and run: 'Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All'
>
> X hyperv does not appear to be installed

so I followed the message displayed and I launched the command:

> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online

and it shows me the following result:

> FeatureName      : Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
>   DisplayName      : Hyper-V
>   Description      : Provides management services and tools for creating and running virtual machines and their resources
>                      virtuels et de leurs ressources.
>   RestartRequired  : Possible
>   State            : Enabled
>   CustomProperties :

Also, I have verified that Hyper-v is installed correctly.
I have minikube 1.7.2 installed.
Any idea how to solve this issues ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried this suggestion, `Suggestion: Start PowerShell as Administrator, and run: 'Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All'`?

Comment: yes, but i still have the same issue

Comment: I haven't dug too deep yet but have been facing this problem all afternoon.  After noticing that minikube 1.7.x was just released in the last week I downgraded to 1.6.2.  Without making any other changes, minikube is now working for me.  I haven't checked to see in which version of 1.7 this problem was introduced, but can at least confirm that 1.6.2 doesn't have the problem so it must be a bug.

Comment: I had a similar problem and here is a possible solution: [My answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64551525/13415889)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

finally, i was able to launch minikube with --force flag, there is an issue with minikube 1.7.2 described here  [#6579](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/6579)

Comment: Good job figuring it out, and thanks for sharing! You should now accept this answer as the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

try

minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv **--force**

Answer (score 1):

Once minikube is installed, run the following command in powershell( as Administrator)

1. minikube config set driver hyperv
2. minikube delete
3. minikube start --vm-driver=Hyper-V

Answer (score 1):

Had to start the command prompt as Administrator and could start minikube with Hyperv.